# MIPS Instruction Register

Tags: mips

> If the bit pattern 0x0C000000 is placed into the Instruction Register, what MIPS instruction will be executed?

I am not sure what this question means by the Instruction Register and how it relates to a bit pattern.

Comment: You're supposed to imagine a non-pipelined single-cycle or multi-cycle MIPS where only one instruction is being worked on at a time.  The bits of that instruction get loaded into a register for use as internal control signals.  Real MIPS CPUs are pipelined and don't have just a single instruction register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 32 bit MIPS instruction `0x0C000000` can be rewritten in binary like this:

```
000011 00000000000000000000000000
opcode target
```

This appears to be the `jal` jump and link instruction.  When executed, it will cause the program to jump to the address specified in `target`.

Answer (score 1):

The Instruction Register or IR as it is commonly abbreviated to is the first part of the MIPS CPU Architecture that executes code. The bit pattern loaded into it determines the OPCODE, Source Registers, Destination register, and memory offsets.

Every programming language is simplified to binary by the compiler/interpreter. Binary of course can be represented in the traditional 1's and 0's or in HEX which is the bit pattern you have supplied in your question.

When a specific command has been converted into it's binary representation each bit of the bit pattern has meaning.

MIPS is a 32-bit architecture so the bits in question are [31 -0] where 0 is the right most bit. (I suggest you read up on Endianess as well). You provided a 16-bit HEX value so I am padding the lowest order bits with 0's

Example of Conversion

```
    0    C    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  0000  1100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

This is a J-type instruction so the following bits mean:

```
opcode [31-25] 
target [24 -0]
```

That being said you can group the binary as such

```
000011 000000000000000000000000
```

Using the resources I have linked to below we can tell the opcode is JAL.

This [link](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/fa13/disc/04/Disc4.pdf) from Berkeley is helpful.

This [link](https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~franklin/154/MipsCheatSheet.pdf) is a scan from the same textbook when I was in my architectures course and I used it a lot.